# When and how we can get $ \sigma(g(x))=g(f(x))$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is about consequence of lemma $7.17$ from David Eisenbud's commutative algebra book.
[image]

That is, we get for $g(x) \in R[[x]]$  $$\varphi(g(x))=g(f(x)).$$
As a **consequence of this corollary**, for any field $K$  with algebraic closure $\bar K$, we have $\varphi: \bar K[[x]] \to \bar K[[x]]$ such that $$\varphi(g(x))=g(f(x)), \ \longrightarrow (1)$$ for $ g(x) \in \bar K[[x]],\ f(x) \in x \bar K[[x]]$.

Then consider the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$.

**My question:** I want to associate or relate the above isomorphism $\varphi \in \text{Aut}(\bar K[[x]])$ with the automorphism $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$.

Is it possible to replace $\varphi$ by $\sigma$ in the formula $(1)$ ?

i.e., when and how we can get $ \sigma(g(x))=g(f(x))$ as in formula $(1)$ ?

**My approach:**

I know that the Galois group i.e., an element $\sigma$ of the Galois group act on the ring $\bar K[[x]]$ or on $O_K[[x]]$ by acting on the coefficients of the power series $g(x)=\sum a_n x^n \in \bar K[[x]]$. 
Then for $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ acting on $\bar K[[x]]$ by $$\sigma(g(x))=\sigma(\sum a_n x^n)=\sum \sigma(a_n)x^n.$$ 
Looking at this, we can ask to get a similar formula like formula $(1)$.

i.e., Is it possible to get an $f' \in x \bar K[[x]]$ and an $g'(x) \in \bar K[[x]]$  such that $\sigma(g'(x))=g'(f'(x)) $  ?

Any hints how to prove or any reference would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the situation here. $\varphi$ and $\sigma$ are both automorphisms of $O_K[[x]]$. That does not mean they are equal.

Comment: @Roland, yes you are correct , I am asking when and under condition the result follows ??

Comment: What result ? When does $\varphi=\sigma$ ? That does not mean anything...

Comment: @Roland, no, can we replace $\varphi$ in $\varphi(g(x))=g(f(x))$ by $\sigma$  under  some condition ?

Comment: You still say the same thing. Maybe give a bit more context. Is it an exercise ? Right now, your question does not make any sense. You have two isomorphisms and you are asking under which condition they are equal. If you are asking if $\sigma=\varphi$ the answer is no, never unless they are both the identity.

Comment: @Roland, I have edited the question. No, I don't need $\varphi=\sigma$.  In the corollary 7.17 ,  $\varphi$ is not unique. So I want to know whether we get another $f' \in x \bar K[[x]]$ and an $g'(x) \in \bar K[[x]]$ such that similar formula $\sigma(g'(x))=g'(f'(x))$ like formula $(1)$ holds or not. Can you check the question again which I edited ?

Comment: With the above modification, yes, it is possible : take $g'=0$. Or take $f'=x$ and $g'\in K[[x]]$.